# Is using HSQLDB considered integration testing? Should I use it?

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, integration-testing

My team uses Redshift and we'd like to validate our queries and general logic without having to rely on pre-existing data. In other words, like in traditional integration testing, we'd like to insert data, do the testing, and then clean up. We reference specific tables + schemas in our DAOs so if we choose to integration test with Redshift, then we'd be inserting into our test DB that some of our customers use (we use this DB in Beta so data is still "production-quality" data, only that Beta has a subset of what Prod does). The nature of our queries are performing aggregations/functions on the dataset - no CUD transactions.

I was wondering if there's some intrinsic value in using Redshift or can I simply rely on HSQLDB (full-control, transparency, and clean-slate)? Does using HSQLDB still fall under the realm of integration testing?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's considered integration test to your repositories, and I'd say it's recommended!

If you use Spring, you can even use `@DataJpaTest`, which creates a in-memory database to your integration tests (https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-testing.html#boot-features-testing-spring-boot-applications-testing-autoconfigured-jpa-test).

Although, you shoukd still need real RedShift for some functional/smoke testing before going production.